# Implementar SweetAlert en lugar de function confirmar

Tags: javascript

Tengo ese codigo:

```
<td style="text-align: center"><a href='eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $crow['id'];?>'><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: darkred" onclick="return confirmar()"></i></a></td>
```

y ese script:

```
function confirmar(){
var respuesta = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar esa entrada??");
if (respuesta == true){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Así como esta funciona perfecto, pero quería implementar la librería de SweetAlert y no hay forma que me funcione, ya probé de varias formas y no me sale, directamente borra la entrada.

Alguien que ya uso SweetAlert que me podría ayudar a implementar en mi código?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas opciones:

Pero primero cambias tu código

```
<td style="text-align: center">
<a href='eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $crow['id'];?>'>
<i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: darkred" onclick="return confirmar()"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

Por algo dinámico para que cada clic solo sea el ID de la entrada y no tu *href* :

```
<td style="text-align: center">
<i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: darkred" onclick="confirmar(<?php echo $crow['id'];?>)"></i>
</td>
```

Y te quedaría algo así con SweetAlert2:

```js
function confirmar(id)
{

  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar esa entrada?',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      window.location="eliminar.php?id="+id
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />

<td style="text-align: center">
<i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: darkred" onclick="confirmar(1)"></i>
</td>
```